# How to count words in JavaScript using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, word-count

I have a simple html text box.  When I "submit" the form that the text box is in, I would like to get a variable with the number of **words** inside using Jquery.  I would also like to check if the inputted text is only letters, numbers and hyphens (also in jquery). I do not need to count the words as the user types, just when the form is submitted. The form won't submit if jquery is turned off so I guess there are no security risks by not using php.  Is this true?

HTML:

```
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' />
<input type='button' value='Sign Up' id='signUp'>
```

JQUERY (attempt):

```
var wordcount = $('#name').val()  // i don't know how to count the words
```

Comment: This would be better titled "How to count words in JavaScript using JQuery."

Comment: _"The form won't submit if jquery is turned off so I guess there are no security risks by not using php. Is this true?"_ - depends what you mean by "security risks": you _must_ validate input server-side because malicious users can use dev tools to bypass your client-side validation. The same validation on the client is an optional extra to improve the user experience. By the way, this isn't really a jQuery thing so much as a "plain" JavaScript regex and `.split()` thing.

Comment: Here's a [Word and Character counter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14010497/383904) in pure **JavaScript**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would split the string and then count the length of the resulting array.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click( function() {
    var words = $('#name').val().split(' ');
    alert(words.length);
});
```

Comment: thanks.  is there a way to check if these characters are only letters numbers and hyphens in jquery?

Comment: yes, you would want to use a regex for that. You can run a test and the result will be true/false if it matches your selection criteria. Regexes are not my strong suit so you may want to ask in a new question. I will take a stab at it anyways.

Comment: This is not going to work so well as every space you put between words will be counted as another words so "help     me" would be 6 words !!

Comment: This works Ok, you can add additional logic to take care of any other string delimiters.

Answer (score 10):

A slight improvement on other answers as is deals with more edge cases. ie using multiple spaces and punctuation together and also handles punctuation at the start and end of text properly.

```
var numOfWords = $('#name').val().replace(/^[\s,.;]+/, "").replace(/[\s,.;]+$/, "").split(/[\s,.;]+/).length;
```

It first strips off any punctuation and spaces at the beginning and end of the text and then counts what's left. Obviously one can add more punctuation (like exclamation marks) if required.

Answer (score 3):

Using the regular expression below allow us to remove any kind of white space (single or multiples) so that the count is very accurate.

```
$('#name').keyup(function(){
   var wordCount = $(this).val().split(/[\s\.\?]+/).length;
   console.log(wordCount);
});
```

See this jQuery plugin I have developed:

https://github.com/mcdesignpro/maxLenght

Comment: I have updated my answer for you @Toby Speight :) Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a better answer as it handles additional whitespace characters e.g. double spaces. It also goes beyond the question and handles line returns if you are using a textarea etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can count the number of words in a string using the JavaScript `split()` method. This method simply split a string into an array of substrings by a specified character which is a space " ". Then display the length of 'words' array.

```
$('input[type="button"]').click( function() {
    var words = $('#name').val().split(" ");
    alert(words.length);
});
```

Here's an example: [How to count words using JQuery](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-count-words-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 2):

Is very useful to remove whitespaces from the beginning and end of the string usign `$.trim()`. You can use `keyup` event for a *realtime* counting.

```
$('#name').keyup(function(){
    var words = $.trim($(this).val()).split(' ');
    console.log(words.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = $('#name').val(),
    count = str.split(' ').length;
```

Assuming that each word is seperated by a space

Comment: im pretty sure that just gives the number of characters.  I'm trying to find the number of words

Comment: I misread on accident.  `split` will separate the string into an array of spaces

Comment: val().length returns a number, there is an error overthere.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple characters to split your source string :

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click( function() {
    var words = $('#name').val().split(/[\s\.,;]+/);
    console.log(words.length);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to count words in JavaScript using JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var words = $.trim($("#name").val()).split(" ");
        alert(words.length);
    });
});
```

See more @ [Count words in JavaScript using JQuery](http://www.jquerypot.com/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-words-in-a-string-with-jquery/)