# Previewing blog post in jekyll site

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I have the index.html page so far using jekyll, here is the quote:

```
---
layout: layout
title: "Posts"
---

<section class="content">
  <ul class="listing">
    {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
        <h1 align="center"><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</section>
```

What I'm trying to do is preview the first 25-30 words of the particular post under the title and link.

What is the best way to go about it? I actually found the solution but I didn't save the link and have now spent 2 days searching to no avail.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: would a set size suffice? ie in a div with `width:200px; overflow:hidden`? or do you want it to be the amount of words?

Comment: Thank you Carrie, I believe a set size will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent version of jekyll, 1.0.x, offers a `post.excerpt` variable for all posts, which consists of he first paragraph of the post. It can quite safely be used to preview the post.

See https://gist.github.com/benbalter/5555369 for details.

Comment: Thank you Polygnome, that's a really neat feature and I appreciate you posting after the topic was closed - you are certainly awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If you're specific about just showing a certain amount of words then you'll need to use Javascript to split content using spaces and count the words ([something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752853/how-to-count-words-in-javascript-using-jquery)).

**Most likely** though, you'd like to show a small section of the post like a preview. If that's the case I'd suggest inserting your post body into a `<p>` with the following CSS:

```
.listing p{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 60%; /* or whatever you'd like */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv9MW/)

This will neatly preview the text with an ellipsis at the end of the width.

Comment: Thank you Carrie, I really appreciate you quick help - you are sorta my hero today, just saying!

Comment: This is not longer necessary in the newest jekyll version, see my answer for details.