# How to Count the Number of Words in a Text File using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stock at something here.

I am trying to integrate a feature on my web application (HTML5) that will enable users choose a text file using normal HTML file input box, and have have the total number of words in the selected text file displayed to them in real-time.

Here is what i have so far on the Javascript part:

```
<script>
    //function to count words in selected text file
    $(function() {
        $('#upload').change( function(event) {
            var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]); //get temp path of selected file

            //some codes here to read the file selected by the user and store the number of words in a string called total_word 
            $("#display_File_count").text(total_word); //display the number of words in the appropriate span
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is the HTML part;

```
<input name="upload" type="file" id="upload" accept="text/plain" accesskey="u">
                <div><span id="display_File_count">0</span> <span> words</span></div>
```

When the user clicks on the file selector and choose a text file, the script should read the text file's contents count number of words contained in it (all done on client's side).

The number of words is then displayed within the span with id "display_file_count".

Please guys I need a way out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752853/how-to-count-words-in-javascript-using-jquery

Comment: Split the string on the space character; count the number of elements in the resultant array

Comment: FileReader API -> async onload property -> FileReader.readAsText -> String.prototype.split on whitespace -> Array.prototype.length. Enjoy.

Comment: @ElGavilan my major issue here is pursing the selected text file on client side, not really doing the counting.

Comment: @Marcel W,  That thread is talking about counting text-box content, which is prety easy. What i need is a way to count the words contained in a selected text file without posing it to the server. (thus, before the form is even submitted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the FileReader (remember to check browser compatibility - becuase it is not supported by all browsers)

```
$('#upload').change( function(event) {

    var f = event.target.files[0];
    if (f) {
        var r = new FileReader();

        r.onload = function(e) { 
            var contents = e.target.result;
            var res = contents.split(" "); 
            $("#display_File_count").text(res.length);
        }
        r.readAsText(f);
    }
});
```

Comment: let me try working around your solution. It looks attractive and positive. Thanks

Comment: That worked great. With little modification i was able to get it working on IE and older FF.